# md-tab-group not displaying XML content

Tags: xml, angular, tabs, blockly

I am trying to display a blockly xml content inside md-tab . but it is not displaying the blockly xml content.

The blockly xml shows up when put outside the tab. Any help is really appreciated and would make me to move forward

Comment: Some code would be helpful to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Given that Blockly doesn't usually display XML, "displaying the blockly xml content" confuses me. Can you clarify what you mean?